# How to measure similarity between two arbitrary files?

Tags: git

I have two arbitrary files. Git does not consider them as one renamed file. Is it possible to measure (in percent) similarity between them?

Comment: You'll need to define what you want as a similarity measurement. (How similar is `hello` to `hello world`? How similar is `hello` to `jello`? What's *your* metric?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe count the lines and compare it with the number of lines in a diff:

```
#!/bin/bash
SIZE1=`wc -l "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1`
SIZE2=`wc -l "$2" | cut -d' ' -f1`

#choose bigger file
SIZEMAX=$(($SIZE1>$SIZE2?$SIZE1:$SIZE2))

SIZEDIFF=`diff -u1 "$1" "$2" | wc -l | cut -d' ' -f1`

#divide second result halved by first result is the amount of change
#1 - amount of change is the similarity

perl -e "print (1.0 - ($SIZEDIFF/2.0) / $SIZEMAX)"
```

Put the code into `similarity.sh` and call as `./similarity.sh x.txt y.txt`
 with the files you want to compare.

Comment: if i use comm, i get "file is not in sorted order" - error.

Comment: _sigh_ - yeah, I'm talking rubbish, ignore me

Answer (score 0):

One may use `git diff -M` to detect renames.

From the `git diff` man page:

> -M[], --find-renames[=]
>              Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, -M90% means Git should consider a delete/add pair to be a
>              rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and is thus the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is
>              the same as -M5%. To limit detection to exact renames, use -M100%. The default similarity index is 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Perl5 solution based on [@Adder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282628/1054397)'s answer that adds a few optimizations in case you are dealing with large files.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use Fcntl 'O_RDONLY';

sub flines ($) {
  my %opts = (
    mode   => O_RDONLY, # No need to cache or write,   
    memory => 0,        #   as we are not using read data.
    recsep => "\n",     # Use "\r\n" if Windows
  );
  tie @_, 'Tie::File', shift, %opts or die "tie: $!\n";
  $_ = scalar @_;
  untie @_;
  return $_
}

sub slines ($) {
  my $fh = $_[0];
  next for <$fh>;
  return $.
}

my ($f1, $f2) = @ARGV;

# count number of lines in unified diff
open my ($fh), "diff -u1 $f1 $f2 |" or die "open: $!\n";

my $sD = slines $fh;
my $s1 = flines $f1;
my $s2 = flines $f2;

printf "%8.3g\n", 1.0 - ( $sD / 2.0 ) / ( $s1 > $s2 ? $s1 : $s2 )
```

It is used and called the same as in his example:

```sh
$ similarity foo bar
   0.327
```